# recursion and for loop in prolog

Tags: for-loop, recursion, prolog, fibonacci

i am trying to translate this code

```
 int countWaysUtil(int n, int m)
 {
    if (n <= 1)
    return n;
    int res = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i<=m && i<=n; i++)
        res += countWaysUtil(n-i, m);
     return res;
 }

 // Returns number of ways to reach s'th stair
 int countWays(int s, int m)
 {
    return countWaysUtil(s+1, m);
 }
```

, found in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-reach-nth-stair/ to a prolog program. The code above, calculates all possible ways to climb to the S'th stair, if you can climb up to m stairs at a time. I have tried the following code in Prolog but it doesn't seem to be right. :/

```
countWays(1,_,1):- !.
countWays(0,_,0):- !.
countWays(S,M,Val):-
   forLoop(S,M,0,Temp).

forLoop(_,1,Res,Res).
forLoop(S,M, Res,Temp):-
   countWays(N-M,M,Val),
   Res is Res + Val.
```

obviously, M is not reduced,which probably causes an infinite loop, because i was not sure where and how it should be done. I would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: `Res is Res+Val`?

Comment: Prolog statements are logical statements. To say that `Res is Res + Val` is to say that you can have a value `Res` which has the value of `Res + Val` which is never true unless `Val` has the value 0. So if `Val` is non-zero, `Res is Res + Val` will fail.

Comment: Also, note that Prolog does *not* evaluate expressions in-line since it is a logic programming language and treats `N-M` simply as a *term* unless you specifically evaluate it using `is/2`, an arithmetic comparison operator, or CL(PFD) expression. So `countWays(N-M, M, Val)` will not evaluate `N-M`. If you want to pass `N-M`, you need to evaluate it first, then pass it: `Diff is N - M, countWays(Diff, M, Val)`.